# Как в Django вычислить количество дней между двумя датами чтобы можно было вычислить сумму за проживание?

Tags: python, django

Есть приложение для онлайн бронирования в Django. Нужно сделать функцию, которая будет считать разницу между двумя датами ( Дата_заезда и Дата_Выезда) и посчитать цену за проживание. К примеру: умножая это количество дней на цену за проживание за один день.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Room: 
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Номер комнаты:")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Название комнаты:")
    is_lux = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Люкс?")



class Offer:
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания бронирования:")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Обновлён в:")
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="Клиент:", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, verbose_name="Комната: ", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Дата заезда")
    departure_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Дата отъезда")
  ?  days_ 
    is_verificated = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Подтверждён?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать метод в модели, например

```
def diff_date(self):
    return (self.departure_date - self.arrival_date).days * cost
```

Comment: А как её потом вызывать? То есть, как использовать в модели? Извиняюсь, новичок в Python.

Comment: `instance.diff_date()` Вообще, смотря где вызывать.

Comment: К примеру, если я захочу вывести в форму весь заказ и снизу чтобы цена считалась в зависимости от количества дней.

Comment: Если вызывать из шаблона, то вешай properly и вызывайте, как `instance.diff_date`